# RXJava 2 Polling with multiple subscribers

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

i would like to start replacing/using RXJava2 for polling instead of Observer and Listeners. Now there is just one Problem. Ive one Polling Observable which should only be started if at least one Subscriber is connected. If multiple subscribers are connected the Interval should be the same. means: One observable repeat the Polling process all n Seconds. If the observable has 1..* subscribers it should keep polling n Seconds and notify all subscribers with the result.

This is how i have done this with Listeners and/or with my RXJava Solution.

My first try is creating a Singleton Class which creates only one PublishSubject. If someone is subscribed it will get the data in onNext(). Now my Polling Observer is started somewhere and push the Data to the Subject. This doesnt work as excepted since it's

- bad pattern design
- doesnt start ONLY if a subscriber is connected and stops if no subscribers are available
- doesnt share the data successfull and requires two classes (for subject and repeating observable)

  ```
  public class SingleTonClass { 
  private PublishSubject<List<Data>> subject = PublishSubject.create();


  public PublishSubject getSubject() {
      return this.subject;
  }

  public void setData(List<Data> data) { 
     subject.onNext(data);
  }
  }
  ```

I would lovely avoid Listener/Interfaces to share the informations around and let rxjava2 do its job.

After a research i figured out that there is refcount() and share() but im not sure if this is the proper way solving this. In my case it's for a REST-Service which polls the server if at least one subscriber is connected elsehow it should stop polling since it doesnt make sense getting the data in this case.

I tried to solve it onec but it doesnt work as excepted:

[Polling using RXJava2 / RXAndroid 2 and Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458428/polling-using-rxjava2-rxandroid-2-and-retrofit?noredirect=1#comment72061390_42458428)

Comment: If you want to have a single Observable with multiple subscribers then `share()` is the way to go with perhaps after a `replay(1)` to make sure that new subscribers get the latest emission.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Observable<Data> dataSource = Observable.interval(INTERVAL, TIME_UNIT)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // make REST requests on IO threads
    .map(n -> {
            return requestData();
        })
    .replay(1);
```

`replay()` operator includes `share()`, which in turn includes `publish()` and `refCount()` functionalities. This makes your observable *hot*, i.e. all subscribers share single subscription. It automatically subscribes (starts new `interval` sequence) with the first subscriber, and unsubscribes (stops `interval`) when last subscriber is gone.

`replay(1)` also caches last emitted value, i.e. new subscribers do not have to wait for new data to arrive.